# Vishay TCST2300 Testing (Transmissive Optical Sensor with Phototransistor Outpu)

Tags: sensor, phototransistor

New here and relatively simple question for those experienced with electronics.  Unfortunately, my experience is limited and I'm confused by the [TCST2300](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81147/tcst2103.pdf) datasheet information.

Specifically, I'm trying to debug an optical encoder on an industrial pyramid roller (an "Ercolina CE50 H3") and I first want to confirm that the encoder board has power to the emitter and a signal voltage to the phototransistor.

Question #1:
From the data sheet (page 3) it looks like I should be looking for 1.25 - 1.60 VDC to the "+" side of the emitter [INPUT (EMITTER) section of the data sheet], and either a minimum of 7 VDC or 70 VDC of signal voltage into the phototransistor.  Therein lies my confusion - am I looking for "Collector emitter voltage" - i.e. minimum 70 VDC, or "Emitter collector voltage" - i.e. minimum 7 VDC (again on page 3 under "OUTPUT (DETECTOR)"?

Question #2:
Once I identify the voltages I'm looking to verify, is it safe to simply take either of these pins to any ground on the machine to check the voltage?  I'm assuming that grounding a pin shouldn't hurt anything.

I know that this is a very basic question and it illustrates my lack of understanding, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the absolute maximum ratings, not the recommended operating conditions. This is a common mistake for those new to this stuff.

The 70V is the absolute maximum \$V_{CEO}\$ (Collector to emitter voltage with base open) and the 7V is the absolute maximum \$V_{ECO}\$, the reverse voltage (maximum voltage at the *emitter* with respect to the collector with base open).

If you measure across the collector to emitter (positive lead to collector) you should see this voltage decrease as light is applied to the detector assuming a resistive load; just what voltage that is I have no idea of (probably somewhere between 5 and 12V with no light at the detector).

Likewise you could measure across the detector photodiode pins which should increase in voltage (from anode to cathode) as more light is detected.

The test circuit shows the output from the emitter but there is no reason it could not be at the collector (which is why I suggest measuring across the device).

Once you have measured across the device you could measure the emitter with respect to ground and at the collector with respect to ground to see where the output is actually taken from.

Comment: Peter Smith – thanks for the quick response! Very helpful and I will post progress.